# MVC 4 Redirect failing with Authorize Attribute, AllowAnonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm adding email verification to an MVC4 website that uses the WebSecurity membership stuff.

If a user registers, we send them an email with a link. If they try to login prior to confirming their registration, WebSecurity.Login() fails. Okay, that's reasonable.

What I need the site to do is recognize that it is awaiting them to complete confirmation and notify them. So I have code like:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && !WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(model.UserName))
{
    // Inform the user
    return RedirectToAction("ConfEmailSent");
}
```

The controller is marked with the [Authorize] attribute and the action itself is marked with [AllowAnonymous].

The Redirect fails, but if I manually change the URL in the browser, it works just fine.

Is this an MVC4 bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: `if I manually change the URL in the browser, it works just fine.`  Could you elaborate more?

Comment: And what do you mean by `The Redirect fails`? What does the user see?

Comment: I'm not sure what to add to the first comment. I thought it was self-explanatory. I modify the URL in the browser's address bar and it brings up the page just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved. Really embarrassing oversight: I omitted the return statement and just called RedirectToAction() in a couple of places. Duh me.

Comment: I thought about just deleting my question but it's a simple oversight that the compiler won't catch for you, so others may bump into it.